# Как выбрать сумму значений из одной таблицы, сгруппировав значения из другой?

Tags: mysql

Имеется 3 таблицы. Характеристика клиентов `clientsInfo`, которая может редактироваться, таблица клиентов, где хранится их информация `clients` и таблица прочтений книг у этих клиентов `clientsReads`.

Если клиент захочет поменять себе имя, то будет запрос не на update, а на insert в таблицу `clientsInfo`. Это сделано, чтобы отслеживать актуальную информацию для дальнейших действий.

Пример содержимого таблиц представлен в [онлайн mysql](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3z3vux6d9), только предварительно надо убрать установку `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Возникает проблема. Для отображения статистики, при выполнении следующего запроса, вначале выбираются все редакции клиента, вместе с его прочтением, а потом суммируется. В итоге ни имя не верно, ни кол-во прочтений.
Запрос:

```
SELECT clients.id, name, sum(amount) as readed, balance
FROM clients
inner join clientsInfo on clientsInfo.clientId=clients.id
left join clientsReads on clientsReads.clientId=clients.id
GROUP BY clients.id;
```

Вывод:

```
Clark  8  123.2
Ava    10 321
```

*Без группировки:

```
Clark       4  123.2
ClarkRename 4  123.2
Ava         10 321
```

Исправив запрос, на предварительную группировку `clientsInfo`, мне удалось исправить проблему с суммой прочтений, но не с актуальной версией. `order by id desc` - не работает во вложенном запросе при группировке, можно ли как-то обойтись без 3-й вложенности запроса и как-то иначе получить желаемый результат? Как правильнее будет сгруппировать таблицу версий?

```
SELECT clients.id, lastVersion.name, sum(amount) as readed, balance
FROM clients
INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT clientId, name
          FROM clientsInfo
          GROUP BY clientId
        ) AS lastVersion
        ON lastVersion.clientId=clients.id
left join clientsReads on clientsReads.clientId=clients.id
GROUP BY clients.id;
```

Вывод:

```
Clark  4  123.2
Ava    10 321
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
ClarkRename 4  123.2
Ava         10 321
```

Comment: `Если клиент захочет поменять себе имя, то будет запрос не на update, а на insert в таблицу clientsInfo. Это сделано, чтобы отслеживать актуальную информацию для дальнейших действий.` - а где в этом решении отслеживание актуальной информации? Зачем стрелять себе в ногу? Это архитектурная ошибка из-за которой приходится костылять запросы

Comment: @InDevX Тогда укажите на то как это исправить. Судя по вашему комментарию - это должно помочь мне в решении возникшей проблемы в запросе, иначе он не по теме вопроса

Comment: Ну, как.. Или апдейт делайте или добавьте [индекс](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/constraint-primary-key.html) + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Если история изменений нужна то её отдельно лучше писать

Comment: @InDevX Да, история изменений нужна. И это и есть отдельная таблица, которая их хранит. Или вы предлагаете делать ещё одну таблицу типо `clientStoryСhanging`? Но тогда, необходимо будет после каждого обновления данных, везде где используется актуальная информация исправлять id из `clientsInfo` на новый id из `clientStoryСhanging` или наоборот, что будет хуже в плане скорости, количества и сложности запросов. На мой взгляд

Comment: Нет, если есть то отдельно ничего не нужно делать. Забыл добавить, если insert с индексом + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE то когда срабатывает апдейт - будет primary key меняться, т.к. запрос всё ещё insert, если это важно то проще обычный апдейт делать

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в таблицу clientsInfo флаг актуальности. При добавлении новой информации отмечайте старую запись как неактуальную. Тогда можно будет легко выбирать из этой таблицы только актуальные записи.

Comment: О, да, это сработает, а запрос исправить никак не получится без этого действия?

Comment: Можно исправить, но запрос будет слишком сложный и тормозной. С двойным вложением подзапросов - сначала выборка максимального id с группировкой по clientId, затем выборка name по этому id, а затем уже с тем, что получится - джойнить. С флагом проще. К тому же флаг может нести полезную информацию , например в качестве флага можно использовать дату потери актуальности.